# Best .NET library for trees

Tags: .net, tree

What is the best .NET library (commercial or open source) that implements a non-binary tree and its associated operations? The requirements are to dynamically insert and delete nodes, copy/paste nodes, find information buried in nodes, copy/paste of folders and their children from one area of the tree to another. The tree is at the business logic layer. Presentation layer is WPF. Implementation language is C#.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'Best'? Fastest seek time? Smallest Memory Footprint? Easy to Query?

Comment: Fast in performance and with learning curve, solid in quality.

Comment: One more thing: tree will be populated from XML or SQLSERVER

Answer (score 4):

I would say [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) without a doubt.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true"),
    new XComment("Comment"),
    new XElement("Employees",
        new XElement("RootElement",
            new XElement("Employee",
                new XAttribute("id", "123"),
                new XElement("name", "John"),
                new XCData("CData")))));

// Selection multiple nodes
var allEmployees = xdoc.Root.Elements("Employees");
// Select single node
var employeeJohn = from node in xdoc.Root.Descendants().Elements("Employees").Elements("Employee")
                   where node.Attribute("id").Value == "123"
                   select node;

// Insert node
XElement newNode = new XElement("NewNode", "Node content");
allEmployees.Add(newNode);

// Delete node
employeeJohn.Remove();
```

Comment: You should probably add an example of how you would dynamically insert and remove nodes on some existing tree.

Answer (score 4):

I would use:

```
class MyTreeNode : List<MyTreeNode>
{
    // declare per-node properties here, e.g.
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Building and rearranging the tree is pretty straightforward:

```
MyTreeNode root = new MyTreeNode {Name = "root"};

MyTreeNode firstChild = new MyTreeNode {Name = "1"};
root.Add(firstChild);

MyTreeNode secondChild = new MyTreeNode { Name = "2" };
root.Add(secondChild);

root.Remove(firstChild);
secondChild.Add(firstChild);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at QuickGraph over at codeplex.

Answer (score 2):

Trees are so easy to write, and specific requirements relatively diverse, that I'm not sure that a "tree library" would be very useful. Why don't you write your own?